# Handle the state of Excel Controls on Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Previously, we fill up a Personal Data Sheet excel file and printed it out. I'm developing now an online system to replace that, but I also included an option there to generate the exact same excel file, fully filled up by the information the user provided through the system. So now instead the user filling up the excel file, the user filled it through the online system instead, and the system now fills it up for him, then downloads it fully filled.

However, there are fields there that I cannot fill up. The Gender field is composed of two ActiveX checkbox objects for "Male" and "Female", while the Civil Status field is a Combo Box. How can I set the value of the fields and check the value of the target checkboxes?

I'm thinking of getting all controls inside the `XSSFWorkbook` and iterating them, checking on each pass if it is the actual control that I want to process, but I don't know where to start.

I already able to populate All of the other fields of the downloadable excel file, the only remaining parts are the Excel Controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no hope for ActiveX controls to be handled by ApachePOI. For the mean time, I achieve my desired output using the following.

1. Open the template that you are using in Excel and change the form control from ActiveX Control into Form Control.

   [image: 2]
2. Check its property. Right click the form control and choose <kbd>Format Control…</kbd> You will see a modal box something like this.

   [image: 3]
3. On the <kbd>Cell Link</kbd> field, specify a empty cell. That cell will hold a boolean value of TRUE or FALSE and will be the one set by ApachePOI. **So if I set B1 as my cell link and then set the cell's value to TRUE, the referencing form control will be checked**.

   Same rules applies with Combo Box but instead of TRUE or FALSE, you need to specify the index of the option you want to select.

Here is the example code:

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference("B1");
XSSFRow row = currentActiveSheet.getRow(cr.getRow());
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());

cell.setCellValue(value);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do the Cell Link on ActiveX Control:

1- Go to DEVELOPER tab

2- Click on Design Mode

3- Right click on the checkbox

4- Go to Properties option

5- Change the LinkedCell value

[image: Properties ActiveX Controll]

The Apache Poi code is the same:

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference("D30");
XSSFRow row = currentActiveSheet.getRow(cr.getRow());
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());
```